# Sigabrt with error that class must have a valid NSEntityDescription

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, error-handling, sigabrt

As you can see in the title I'm getting a `Sigabrt` with error that class must have a valid `NSEntityDescription`. My answer is what I have to add to my project and where I have to implement this. If this is a obvious question don't judge me because I have just started with `Swift` & `Core Data` coding.

```swift
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc (Trancsaction)
public class Trancsaction: NSManagedObject {
    var date: Date?{
        get{
            return rawDate as Date?
        }
        set {
            rawDate = newValue as NSDate?
        }
    }
    convenience init?(money: Double, date: Date?, reason: String?) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

        guard let context = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(entity: Trancsaction.entity(), insertInto: context)

        self.reason = reason
        self.money = money
        self.date = date
    }
}
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An NSManagedObject of class 'Your Class' must have a valid NSEntityDescription.'

Try to define 

`//@objc(Your Class)
public class YourClass: NSManagedObject {
}`
check this

Comment: Can you how some code ??

Comment: @iOS.Wolf I added the core data class code

Comment: @RohitMagdum I already have this: I added this part of the code to my question.

Comment: How is `entity()` defined? And why a failable initializer? If `AppDelegate` was missing the app would even launch and the managed object context is supposed to be non-optional.

Comment: Is the name of the entity "Transaction"?

Comment: @Willeke yes it is

Comment: @vadian I created a entity for the init with  the class Transaction add added the .entity() to create a new entity. I did this in a class before ( Member) but there it works. Was that what you meant or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Is the class name in the data model "Transaction" or "Trancsaction"?

Comment: yeah it actually is Trancsaction I found the error. It was because of this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try commenting this line `@objc (Trancsaction)`

```
//@objc (Trancsaction)
public class Trancsaction: NSManagedObject {
```